# SwiftUI: Toolbar jitters when toggling sidebar (macOS)

Tags: macos, swiftui

When I toggle the sidebar in my macOS app from the toolbar, sometimes the share button on the upper right jitters (see video). This does not happen on every click, so it might take a few tries to reproduce with the example. The app I am working on has much more content, and there it happens more frequently.

I assume this has something to do with using two `.toolbar` modifiers: When I move the sidebar button to the content area and trigger from there, it seems like the jittering is gone.

Any idea how to fix this? I was not able to recreate this toolbar button layout without using two `.toolbar` modifiers. Code below video.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar")
                .frame(width: 300)
                .toolbar {
                    sidebarButton
                }
            Text("Content")
            .frame(minWidth: 500)
                .toolbar {
                    shareButton
                }
        }
        .frame(height: 500)
    }

    var sidebarButton: some View {
        Button {
            NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(
                #selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil
            )
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
        }
    }

    var shareButton: some View {
        Button {
            print("Share")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm the jitter, also noticed it now in one of my apps. There it seems like the main toolbar tries to display a ">>" on the trailing edge for a moment ... unfortunately I don't have a fix.